# Constraint constant based on screen height

Tags: ios, constraints

So I have a view that contains some elements (Label and Text View) that are 8px spaced between each other. However, added together, the height of the view is too big for some smaller screen size. I want to know how I can change the constraint constant (currently at 8px leading and trailing between each element) based on the screen height.

For example, for a iPhone 8 Plus I would want a 8px spacing. For a iPhone 8 I would want a 7px spacing. For a iPhone 4s, I would want a 5px spacing.

Showing how to do this on a storyboard rather than code would be super helpful.

Look at picture for a better understanding
[image: Image1]
[image: Image3]

Comment: “For example, for a iPhone 8 Plus I would want a 8px spacing. For a iPhone 8 I would want a 7px spacing. For a iPhone 4s, I would want a 5px spacing.” that’s a bad way to think about it. Don’t start examining phone types and changing constraint constants. Just use a stack view to distribute the labels evenly and set inequality constraints on the stack view height.

Comment: If it becomes too big make it a scroll view or implement it in a `UITableView`. Changing the padding, view size for each screen size is not recommended and as far as i know no one does it either.

Comment: Constraint not always must be equal, you can add constraint moreThan or lessThan.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the feedback, I went ahead and changed the view to a stack view. How would I set the inequality constraints so the view will fit all screen sizes and will adjust accordingly? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know what your exact specifications are.

Answer (score 0):

Make it in UIScrollView instead of UIView.

Anyway, you will need to scroll content when the keyboard appears. Otherwise, a user will not see what he writes in the field.

More than you will not have to make different padding between elements.

BUT. If you want to make different paddings yet, try to make depending on 
**UIScreen.main.bounds.height**